# How to upload file to BOX in VBA using API

Tags: excel, vba, api, upload, box

I am trying to upload file in user computer to BOX using API. On GitHub I found this: https://github.com/Tackgnol/VBA-BOX-API/blob/master/mBox.bas

Box Sync and Box Drive are not solution (cannot force user install).

When I printed StatusText I got "Method Not Allowed".

65853643834 is folder id got from url. 
h5ntjo525se0tbhwswq8ozpoqsge**** is from Box Dev "Client ID"

[image]

```
Sub UploadFile()
    UploadBoxFile "h5ntjo525se0tbhwswq8ozpoqsge****"
End Sub

Sub UploadBoxFile(ByVal sToken As String)
    Dim curlInput As XMLHTTP60
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim sXMLInput As String

    Set curlInput = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

    sQuery = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"

    sXMLInput = "attributes={name: ""fileSample.txt"", ""parent"": {""id"":         ""65853643834""}}" & vbNewLine & "file=C:\Users\MichalPalko\Downloads\fileSample.txt"

    curlInput.Open "POST", sQuery, False

    curlInput.setRequestHeader "Authorization:", "Bearer " & sToken & 3243
    curlInput.send sXMLInput
    Debug.Print curlInput.StatusText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue but made some adjustments to your code and am receiving the StatusText response of "Unsupported Media Type".

I feel like I'm so close but stabbing in the dark here.  Did you ever figure it out?

My adjusted code is below:

```
Sub UploadBoxFile(sFilePath As String)
    Dim curlInput 'As XMLHTTP60
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim sXMLInput As String

    Dim sToken As String
    Dim sFolderID As String
    Const sP As String = """"
    Const sAp As String = "'"

    sQuery = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content"
    sToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"     'My Obscured token
    sFolderID = "1234567890"                 'My Obscured FolderID
    sFileName = "TEST File 0001a.txt"

    sXMLInput = "attributes=" & sAp & "{" & sP & "name" & sP & ":" & sP & sFileName _
        & sP & ", " & sP & "parent" & sP & ":{" & sP & "id" & sP & ":" & sP & sFolderID & sP & "}}" & sAp _
        & vbNewLine & "file=" & sFilePath

Debug.Print sXMLInput

    Set curlInput = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With curlInput
        .Open "POST", sQuery, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization:", "Bearer " & sToken
        .send sXMLInput
        Debug.Print .StatusText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi cows, after all I have changed method. Now I use uploading to box via email (using company SMTP). But if you find out how to go with this, please let us know! :)